# IP Camera interface with python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to connect an ip camera with opencv on python but no connection is established. This ip camera works on an android application V380. I could open it with this application but using opencv. I failed

Comment: Is this an rtsp camera?  Can you connect to it with, say, ffplay (e.g. "ffplay rtsp://user:password@ipaddress") ?  Are you on linux or on windows?

Comment: I am windows. Actually there is no details about rtsp or http.In addition can you tell me more about ffplay

Comment: Hi, google is your friend.  Try "ffplay" and "rtsp".  In brief, "rtsp" is a standard protocol for communicating with IP cameras.  If your camera is "rtsp" or "onvif" compatible, you can connect to it with any standard software from a desktop computer.  If its some weird/cheap chinese brand using its own protocols, there's no way to connect to it

Comment: okay... thanks any way bro

Comment: If you have the rtsp link of the camera you can use opencv VideoCapture directly. If you can say at least the model of the cam, and how are you trying to connect. This way we can actually help you know if you are doing it correctly or if the link is not the correct one. The address is most probably `rtsp://admin:password@ipOfCam/live/ch00_0`. Not sure if you need to set the port for this camera, so it could be `rtsp://admin:password@ipOfCam:554/live/ch00_0`

Answer (score 1):

test this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:password@192.168.70.68", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Frame is empty")
        break;
    else:
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```